# How to make part of regex pattern optional?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Im working with this regex pattern:

```
|img_class.*?<img src="(.*?)"(.*?)<\/td>|ms
```

But I want to make it so `<img src="(.*?)"` is optional (not just the src part), because the img_class td is sometimes empty and when it is my pattern fails.

I tried `|img_class.*?(<img src="(.*?)")?(.*?)<\/td>|ms` but it never match.

(I know I could use xpath or something better but im using a pretty big class and i dont want to recode everything right now).

Comment: Could you add a sample of the text you want a match on? Width and without the optional part. Because your updated regex appears to be correct.

Comment: As a note, there's better than regexps to parse HTML, there's actual SGML/HTML parsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
|img_class.*?(?:<img src="(.*?)")?(.*?)<\/td>|ms
```

Comment: As far as I can see you only made the first group none-capturing, that would help the problem if the whole regex never results in a match.

Comment: Didn't work, I am trying to match <td class="img_class"><img src="url"/></td>, but when no image exists the regex keeps going until an image is found and then a td close tag.